# Can't print a string array with a char pointer

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, char

I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char a[] = "ciao";

    char *aPtr = a;

    printf("%s\n", *aPtr);
}
```

It gives me this warning:

```
8:17: warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the
      argument has type 'char' [-Wformat]
        printf("%s\n", *aPtr);
                ~~     ^~~~~
                %c
1 warning generated.
```

If I run it I got segmentation fault

```
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Why?

Comment: Drop the `*`: `printf("%s\n", *aPtr);` -> `printf("%s\n", aPtr);`. As the error says you're passing a `char` when a `char*` is required (for `%s`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the '*' you have in the printf. You need to provide a memory adress in order to the function to be able to seek for the rest of the string.

```
printf("%s\n", aPtr);
```

You're just sending printf a 'c' (the first character of "ciao"). Hope this helps.